# JUnit test fail

Tags: java, junit

I am testing a class called SetOfUsers and I am testing a method as followes:

```
   public void testAddUser() 
    {
        System.out.println("addUser");
        User aUser = new User("Bob","abc123","Manager");
        SetOfUsers instance = new SetOfUsers();
        instance.addUser(aUser);
        System.out.print(aUser);
        assertEquals("Bob,abc123,Manager", instance);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
       // fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
```

However, this test fails the output message I am getting displays

```
testAddUser Failed: expected: <Bob, abc123,Manager> but was: <[Staff Name:Bob]>
```

Comment: You compare a String and an Object SetOfUsers. I'd tell you to implement the "equals()" method of setOfUsers in order to compare what is in it.

Answer (score 0):

'instance' is a class of type SetOfUsers. You are then comparing this to a String. You need to compare it with an example object, or turn the 'instance' into a String first.

Answer (score 0):

**assertEquals("Bob,abc123,Manager", instance);**
One parameter contain the `String` whereas second contain the object of class `SetOfUsers`

Answer (score 0):

```
assertEquals("Bob,abc123,Manager", instance);
```

where

```
"Bob,abc123,Manager" instanceof String
```

and

```
instance instanceof SetOfUsers
```

fails always because

```
String.class != SetOfUsers.class
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

assertEquals("Bob,abc123,Manager", instance.toString());

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what the output of "instance.toString()" actually is and use that to compare against in the assertEquals method.

assertEquals(, instance);